# HTTP 404 versus 596

Tags: http, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

I noticed that sometimes 596 HTTP status code is used for "Service Not Found". Why is 596 used.

We already have 404 for "Not Found".

I understand 404 is mostly for "Resource Not Found" and 596 might mean the endpoint itself is not found.

Is my understanding correct?

Thanks in advance
Doc

Answer (score 0):

There is no registered status code "596".

Where did you see that?

Comment: Mashery Gateway default response is 596 for URIs that are not found

Comment: Their docs say "596: Invalid preflight CORS request: Missing Origin header or Request's Http Method is not OPTIONS". But still, this doesn't make any sense (not in the 5xx range, and no with a custom code).